Exception classes implementing interface
I have a bunch of my application specific exceptions.
For ex:
ProductNotFoundException
OutOfStockException
DiscontinuedProductException
...
...

I think these exception classes can implement an interface. I would like to expose some data as part of exception
   ex.getErrorCode()
   ex.getProductId()

But is it a good practice?. Do we have any such example within JDK ?

I believe there are two possible issues: 1. the inability to rethrow  interface when you need that, i.e. something like: void handle(BusinessException ex) {log(ex); throw ex;} 2. the inability to determine which handler to use when exception implements multiple interfaces.

There are examples for this in the JDK:

sun.print.PrintJobAttributeException implements javax.print.AttributeException
sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException implements javax.print.FlavorException
java.sql.SQLException implements Iterable<Throwable>

But IMHO your main concern should not be whether there are examples in the JDK, your main concern should be whether this leads to better code in your project.

I don`t think it is a good practice.
According to GhostCat`s answer to why-exception-is-a-class-and-not-a-interface-in-java,

There is no point in using interfaces when you want to give a core library element to your users that includes implementation.


Beyond that: interfaces are useful to allow different "views" on classes. In other words: Integer for example can be seen as Comparable. There might be situations where it is perfectly fine to only address an Integer object as a Comparable. But the true essential nature of Integer is still: it is a class representing a whole number of a certain range.


Now think about exceptions! What would be the conceptual "sense" in having public class Foo implements Exception? What would Foo be about "without" that exception view?! In other words: exceptions are also conceptually "important" enough to stand as distinct classes!

Since exceptions are like implementations, and conceptually "important" enough to stand as distinct classes, so I don`t think it is a good practice
